Decomposition of $GL_n$ into unitary and diagonal matrices.
Let $GL_n$ be the invertible $n * n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, let $D_n$ be the $n * n$ diagonal matrices and let $U_n$ be the unitary matrices, again all with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that we can write $GL_n$ as $U_n  D_n U_n$, that is, for every $A \in GL_n$ there exist $U_1, U_2 \in U_n$ and $M \in D_n$ such that $A = U_1 M U_2$?
Furthermore, suppose we replaced $GL_n$ by $SL_n$, (that is, special linear matrices), and $U_n$ by $SU_n$ (special unitary matrices), does the result still hold true?
I suspect the answer is yes but I am having trouble proving it.

Perhaps you could attempt some sort of Gram-Schmidt like procedure?

Actually this is Singular Value Decomposition
